# admin-on-rest toggle menu (show / hide)

Tags: reactjs, menu, onclick, show-hide, admin-on-rest

I'm using admin-on-rest in my react application as admin interface.
My problem is the menu, I'm add a DashboardMenuItem to toggle (show/hide) the menu. But I have no idea what the onClick function should look like and I find no example of this in the documentary or somewhere else.

Can anyone help me by giving an example for this?

My Code:

```
const Menu = ({ hasDashboard, onMenuTap, resources, translate, logout }) => (
  <div style={styles.main}>
    <WithPermission value='ROLE_SA'>
      {hasDashboard && <DashboardMenuItem onClick={onMenuTap} />}
    </WithPermission>
    {resources
      .filter(r => r.list)
      .map(resource => (
        <MenuItemLink
          key={resource.name}
          to={`/${resource.name}`}
          primaryText={translatedResourceName(resource, translate)}
          leftIcon={<resource.icon />}
          onClick={onMenuTap}
        />
      ))}
    {/* <MenuItemLink primaryText='Reports' key='reports' to={`/reports`} leftIcon={<UserIcon />} onClick={onMenuTap} /> */}
    <WithPermission value='ROLE_SA'>
      <SelectField floatingLabelText='Language for Datasets' onChange={LocaleSwitcher}>
        <MenuItem value={'de'} primaryText='DE' />
        <MenuItem value={'en'} primaryText='EN' />
      </SelectField>
    </WithPermission>
    {logout}
    <img src={Logo} style={{maxWidth: '100%', margin: '0 auto'}} />
  </div>
)
```

Comment: Just a note but if you use `react-admin` (the new latest and shiny version of `admin-on-rest`) this feature comes for free ;)

Comment: Thanks men nice tip, but I can't use react-admin at the moment because I have problems by upgrading from old admin-on-rest to the new react-admin version.

Comment: Can we help you with that ?